# How to use tensorflow to ingest sharded CSVs

Tags: python, tensorflow

*This is a problem I am working on in google cloud platform with tensorflow v1.15*

I am working on [this notebook](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/machine_learning/deepdive/03_tensorflow/labs/c_dataset.ipynb) 
In this section, I am supposed to return a function that feeds *model.train()*

```py
CSV_COLUMNS = ['fare_amount', 'pickuplon','pickuplat','dropofflon','dropofflat','passengers', 'key']
DEFAULTS = [[0.0], [-74.0], [40.0], [-74.0], [40.7], [1.0], ['nokey']]

# TODO: Create an appropriate input function read_dataset
def read_dataset(filename, mode):
    #TODO Add CSV decoder function and dataset creation and methods
    return dataset

def get_train_input_fn():
  return read_dataset('./taxi-train.csv', mode = tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN)

def get_valid_input_fn():
  return read_dataset('./taxi-valid.csv', mode = tf.estimator.ModeKeys.EVAL)
```

I think it should be like this:

```py
def read_dataset(filename, mode, batch_size = 512):
  def fn():
    def decode_csv(value_column):
      columns = tf.decode_csv(value_column, record_defaults = DEFAULTS)
      features = dict(zip(CSV_COLUMNS, columns))
      label = features.pop(LABEL_COLUMN)
      return features, label

    # Create list of file names that match "glob" pattern (i.e. data_file_*.csv)
    filenames_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(filename)
    # Read lines from text files
    textlines_dataset = filenames_dataset.flat_map(tf.data.TextLineDataset)
    # Parse text lines as comma-separated values (CSV)
    dataset = textlines_dataset.map(decode_csv)

    if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        num_epochs = None # indefinitely
        dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size = 10 * batch_size)
    else:
        num_epochs = 1 # end-of-input after this

    dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs).batch(batch_size)

    return dataset
  return fn
```

That is actually reflective of code in the video recap that accompanies this notebook, and very similar to my own attempts before I saw that recap.  It is also similar to the [next notebook](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/machine_learning/deepdive/03_tensorflow/labs/d_traineval.ipynb), but that code also unfortunately fails.

With the above code, I am getting this error:

```
UnimplementedError: Cast string to float is not supported
     [[node linear/head/ToFloat (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1748) ]]
```

So, I'm not sure how to transform the data to match the datatype.. I cannot cast the data in *decode_csv* like:

```py
      features = {CSV_COLUMNS[i]: float(cols[i]) for i in range(1, len(CSV_COLUMNS) - 1)}
```

because the error is happening the line before that is called.

Investigating the data I note:

```py
import csv

with open('./taxi-train.csv') as f: 
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    print(next(reader))
```

```
['12.0', '-73.987625', '40.750617', '-73.971163', '40.78518', '1', '0']
```

that looks like the raw data might actually be a string .. am I correct? How can I solve this?

***edit*** *: I have located the* [csv file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/master/courses/machine_learning/deepdive/03_tensorflow/taxi-train.csv), *it is **not** raw string data. Why is the tensorflow import bringing it in as text??*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `training-data-analyst` repository you mentioned, also has the solutions to all the notebooks.

From analysing the provided solution it looks like the `def fn()` part is reduntant. the `read_dataset` function should simply return a `tf.Data.dataset`:

```
def read_dataset(filename, mode, batch_size = 512):
  def decode_csv(row):
    columns = tf.decode_csv(row, record_defaults = DEFAULTS)
    features = dict(zip(CSV_COLUMNS, columns))
    features.pop('key') # discard, not a real feature
    label = features.pop('fare_amount') # remove label from features and store
    return features, label

  # Create list of file names that match "glob" pattern (i.e. data_file_*.csv)
  filenames_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(filename, shuffle=False)
  # Read lines from text files
  textlines_dataset = filenames_dataset.flat_map(tf.data.TextLineDataset)
  # Parse text lines as comma-separated values (CSV)
  dataset = textlines_dataset.map(decode_csv)

  # Note:
  # use tf.data.Dataset.flat_map to apply one to many transformations (here: filename -> text lines)
  # use tf.data.Dataset.map      to apply one to one  transformations (here: text line -> feature list)

  if mode == tf.estimator.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
      num_epochs = None # loop indefinitely
      dataset = dataset.shuffle(buffer_size = 10 * batch_size, seed=2)
  else:
      num_epochs = 1 # end-of-input after this

  dataset = dataset.repeat(num_epochs).batch(batch_size)

  return dataset
```

The solutions are located i the same directory as `labs`. So for example the solution for
`training-data-analyst/courses/machine_learning/deepdive/03_tensorflow/labs/c_dataset.ipynb`
is located at
`training-data-analyst/courses/machine_learning/deepdive/03_tensorflow/c_dataset.ipynb`

Comment: the use of the inner _fn_ was actually from the solution recap video that accompanies the lab (that was the main different between what I had tried on my own and the one that I provided). I'll retry the lab with the solution for the lab and if it works try to build from there, and come back and mark this as the answer. But I can note in advance that if it is only redudent, it is still not working.

Comment: It is possible that the video was recorded for different tensorflow version.   
Best of luck with the labs!